# Error: Invalid address

Tags: web3js, truffle

I keep encountering an error saying invalid address. Why is this?

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const contract = require('truffle-contract');

const MyContract = require('../build/contracts/MyContract.json'

web3 = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545');

var Contract = contract(MyContract);

Contract.setProvider(web3);

Contract.new()
    .then(instance => {
    c = instance;
    return c.getCreator();
})
   .catch(error => {
    console.log(`${error}`);
})
```

MyContract.json:

```
{
 "contract_name": "MyContract",
 "abi": [
{
  "constant": true,
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "getCreator",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "type": "address"
    }
  ],
  "payable": false,
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "constant": true,
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "getContractAddress",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "type": "address"
    }
  ],
  "payable": false,
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "constant": false,
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "newMessage",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "name": "setMessage",
  "outputs": [],
  "payable": false,
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "constant": true,
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "getLastCaller",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "type": "address"
    }
  ],
  "payable": false,
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "constant": true,
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "getMessage",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "payable": false,
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [],
  "payable": false,
  "type": "constructor"
}
  ],
 "unlinked_binary": "0x6060604052341561000f57600080fd5b5b60008054600160a060020a03191633600160a060020a031617905560408051908101604052600b81527f68656c6c6f20776f726c6400000000000000000000000000000000000000000060208201526002908051610072929160200190610079565b505b610119565b828054600181600116156101000203166002900490600052602060002090601f016020900481019282601f106100ba57805160ff19168380011785556100e7565b828001600101855582156100e7579182015b828111156100e75782518255916020019190600101906100cc565b5b506100f49291506100f8565b5090565b61011691905b808211156100f457600081556001016100fe565b5090565b90565b6103c0806101286000396000f300606060405263ffffffff7c01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000350416630ee2cb10811461006957806332a2c5d014610098578063368b8772146100c7578063880b36e71461011a578063ce6d41de14610149575b600080fd5b341561007457600080fd5b61007c6101d4565b604051600160a060020a03909116815260200160405180910390f35b34156100a357600080fd5b61007c6101e4565b604051600160a060020a03909116815260200160405180910390f35b34156100d257600080fd5b61011860046024813581810190830135806020601f820181900481020160405190810160405281815292919060208401838380828437509496506101e995505050505050565b005b341561012557600080fd5b61007c610229565b604051600160a060020a03909116815260200160405180910390f35b341561015457600080fd5b61015c610239565b60405160208082528190810183818151815260200191508051906020019080838360005b838110156101995780820151818401525b602001610180565b50505050905090810190601f1680156101c65780820380516001836020036101000a031916815260200191505b509250505060405180910390f35b600054600160a060020a03165b90565b305b90565b60028180516101fc9291602001906102e2565b506001805473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff191632600160a060020a03161790555b50565b600154600160a060020a03165b90565b610241610361565b60028054600181600116156101000203166002900480601f0160208091040260200160405190810160405280929190818152602001828054600181600116156101000203166002900480156102d75780601f106102ac576101008083540402835291602001916102d7565b820191906000526020600020905b8154815290600101906020018083116102ba57829003601f168201915b505050505090505b90565b828054600181600116156101000203166002900490600052602060002090601f016020900481019282601f1061032357805160ff1916838001178555610350565b82800160010185558215610350579182015b82811115610350578251825591602001919060010190610335565b5b5061035d929150610373565b5090565b60206040519081016040526000815290565b6101e191905b8082111561035d5760008155600101610379565b5090565b905600a165627a7a72305820288648f994114d01cacb3c65b915c20822314d9a7ef26f4443023fd8d3fd582c0029",
"networks": {
"1511991611574": {
  "events": {},
  "links": {},
  "updated_at": 1512075083651
},
"1512085348050": {
  "events": {},
  "links": {},
  "updated_at": 1512086332107
}
 },
 "schema_version": "0.0.5",
 "updated_at": 1512086505628
}
```

Comment: Can you share the MyContract.json file?

Comment: @KarthikeyanThangavel Just shared

Comment: show your index.js it should be in node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js

Answer (score 0):

In your MyContract.json file address field was empty which means your contract was not deployed properly. Make sure your contract was deployed and the address of the contract was updated in the JSON file.